# Find a formula for a sequence of number

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

A sequence starts at $n=1$: $\{1, 4, 13, 40, 121, 364... \}$.

Find an explicit formula that generates these numbers.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably http://oeis.org/A003462

Comment: $U_{n+1}=3U_n+1$

Comment: @AndresCaicedo And don't forget poor [A076040](http://oeis.org/A076040).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good technique to employ on such problems is to calculate the differences between consecutive terms. Here you get:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
a_n:&1&4&13&40&121&364\\
a_n-a_{n-1}:&&3&9&27&81&243
\end{array}$$

The numbers in the last line should look **very** familiar: they’re consecutive powers of $3$. It appears that $a_n=1+3+3^2+\ldots+3^{n-1}$; to get your answer, just find the sum of the geometric series.

Since you included the `(recursion)` label, you might also note that since the bottom line of the table seems to show that $a_n-a_{n-1}=3^{n-1}$, the sequence is apparently generated by the recurrence and initial datum

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&a_1=1\\
&a_n=a_{n-1}+3^{n-1}\text{ if }n>1\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$

(The recurrence could just as well start with $a_0=0$.)

Answer (score 3):

There are infinitely many possibilities. After all, the next term **could** be $-123$, or $\pi$.

But note that the *given* terms are $1$, $1+3$, $1+3+3^2$, $1+3+3^2+3^3$, and so on. You probably know a formula for the sum of the geometric series $1+3+3^2+\cdots +3^{n-1}$.

**Remark:** How did I spot this possibility? One more or less automatic thing one does with a sequence is to take **differences** of successive terms. We get $3$, $9$, $27$, $81$, $243$, a very familiar sequence. Actually, that's not how I knew. I *remembered* the numbers because they come up in a weighing puzzle. The more mathematics one has seen and done, the easier things get.

Answer (score 2):

Let the $r$th term be $t_r$ and the sum of $r$ terms be $S_r$ where $r\ge 1$

$S_n=1+4+13+40+121+364+\cdots+t_n$

$S_n=\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space     1+4+13+40+121+364+\cdots+t_n$

Subtracting $0=1+(4-1)+(13-4)+(40-13)+\cdots+(t_n-t_{n-1})-t_n$

So, $t_n=1+3+3^2+3^3+\cdots $ upto $n$ terms$=\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}=\frac{3^n-1}2$

As requested for the sum,

(1)So, $$S_n=\sum_{1\le r\le n}t_n=\frac12\sum_{1\le r\le n}\left(3^r-1\right)$$
$$=\frac12\sum_{1\le r\le n}3^r-\frac12\sum_{1\le r\le n}1=\frac12\left(\frac{3(3^n-1)}{3-1}\right)-\frac12n=\frac{3^{n+1}-2n-3}4$$

(2)

$S_n=1+4+13+40+121+364+\cdots+\frac{3^{n-1}-1}2+\frac{3^n-1}2$

$3S_n=\space\space\space\space\space\space\space     3+12+39+120+363+\cdots+\frac{3^n-3}2+\frac{3^{n+1}-3}2$

So, $$S_n-3S_n=1+(4-3)+(13-12)+\cdots+(\frac{3^n-1}2-\frac{3^n-3}2)-\frac{3^{n+1}-3}2$$

$$\implies -2S_n=-\frac{3^{n+1}-3}2+(1+1+\cdots+\text{ up to }n \text{ terms})=n-\frac{3^{n+1}-3}2=\frac{2n+3-3^{n+1}}2$$

So, $$S_n=\frac{3^{n+1}-2n-3}4$$

Comment: could you tell what'd be sum of such series considering n terms? . What I do is after finding `tn` , I write `Sn` two times same as you but then I multiply second `Sn` by 3 and then substract . Though my technique is correct but I never get the correct answer as in book , can you please confirm the answer? . Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, please find the edited answer.

Comment: My book shows answer is  `n/4(3^(n+1 - 2n -3)` o0

Answer (score -1):

The Correct answer is

```
((3^n)-1)/2  
n=1 -->  3-1/2=1
n=2 -->  9-1/2=4
n=3 -->  27-1/2=13
n=4 -->  81-1/2=40
n=5 -->  243-1/2=121
n=6 -->  729-1/2=364
.
. 
.
```